# Greek characters in legacy MFC Graphics via TextOut

Tags: c++, graphics, mfc, gdi

For a legacy MFC (C++ Win32) app we are using pDC->TextOut to show units on a value.  This gives the correct output on a English (US) configured Windows computer.

[image]

However, when a user has a Korean configured Windows computer, this is being displayed.

[image]

Per the image, the Korean deployment loses the Greek "mu" as well as the trailing "m".

The relevant (very old) code is of this form...

```
m_fontParameter.CreateFont (m_nRowHeight*75/100, 0, 0, 0, 400,
                            FALSE, FALSE, 0, ANSI_CHARSET,
                            OUT_DEFAULT_PRECIS, 
                            CLIP_DEFAULT_PRECIS,
                            DEFAULT_QUALITY, 
                            DEFAULT_PITCH|FF_SWISS, "Arial") ;
pFontOld = pDC->SelectObject(&m_fontParameter) ;
    
CString strUnits;
strUnits.Format("µm");
pDC->SetTextAlign(TA_BASELINE|TA_RIGHT) ;
pDC->TextOut(nDecimalX-nLeftSize, nBaselineY, strUnits) ;
```

How can I fix this?  Note: there are 100's of these kinds of TextOut calls throughout the code, so please let me know if there is an efficient way to address this for all of them.

Comment: It looks like you are using [codepages](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/intl/code-page-identifiers).  The US and Korean code-pages will have different characters at the same position.  There is no easy fix short term other than seeing if the Korean code-page contains the necessary characters and changing the code to use them it it does. The long term fix is to move the whole application to Unicode on MS-Windows UTF-16le is the default version of Unicode. See [Internationalization for Windows Applications](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/intl/international-support)

Comment: What is the character used for μ? 0xB5 (micro symbol) or 0xEC (Greek small letter μ in codepage 1253-Greek)? I guess the former, because it does work on a computer with English (I guess 1252) codepage. Not sure if the Korean codepage (which one?) you are using even contains the μ character. The ANSI versions of text functions are affected by the current default codepage, unfortunately. You can convert the strings to be printed to Unicode, using the `MultiByteToWideChar()` function and display them using `TextOutW()` (not having to change all the project to Unicode).

Comment: Forgot to mention, if you only need to display the micro symbol, you don't need to convert anything, just use a (wide) string literal. The Unicode character for micro is U+00B5 (\x00B5).

Comment: Currently I use "Alt-230" to create the µ symbol in the string.  What should I do to these lines of code?

strUnits.Format("µm");  

pDC->TextOut(nDecimalX-nLeftSize, nBaselineY, strUnits) ;

Comment: Use `CStringW`, and pass a wide character string into `Format`, e.g. `CStringW strUnits; strUnits.Format(L"µm");`. Ideally, you would port the entire application to use Unicode, but if that is not an option, you can use Unicode only where necessary.